# triggers on opportunity stage and probability to prevent the opportunity stage from regressing to a lesser value

Tags: trigger, soql, opportunity

For example, probability is high like 70% and it will not revert back with decreasing of probability.

Like negotiation review - 90

And it will not back to Value proposition - 50

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a trigger for this. You can do this with a validation rule. Here's an example rule that you could work with and modify: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goLJAAY.